# Is there in lodash comparing two arrays of objects that will not be shown if there's same result

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two json type of data "A" and "B" they have both same types category

```
{
"A":
    [{ 
    "id": "1",
       "vehicle": {
        "model": "toyota"
            }
    },{
    "id":"2",
         "vehicle": {
        "model": "vios"
            }
    },{
    "id":"3",
         "vehicle": {
        "model": "honda"
            }
    },{
    "id":"4",
         "vehicle": {
        "model": "eon"
            }
    },{
    "id":"5",
         "vehicle": {
        "model": "motor"
            }
     }]
}
---------------------------------------------------------
{
    "B":
        [{ 
            "model": "volkswagen"
        },{
            "model": "hyundai"
        },{
            "model": "honda"
        },{
            "model": "mitsubishi"
        },{
            "model": "bmw"
        }]
}
```

Is there's a lodash function do is use ? if there's same model of vehicle in "A" comparing into "B" the model will not be shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using native Javascript, you can use `array#filter` and `array#some`.

Here it will fetch cars which have no model in your models array.

```js
const cars = {"A":[{"id": "1","vehicle": {"model": "toyota"}},{"id":"2","vehicle": {"model": "vios"}},{"id":"3","vehicle": {"model": "honda"}},{"id":"4","vehicle": {"model": "eon"}},{"id":"5","vehicle": {"model": "motor"}}]};

const models = {"B":[{"model": "volkswagen"},{"model": "hyundai"},{"model": "honda"},{"model": "mitsubishi"},{"model": "bmw"}]};

var result = cars.A.filter((car) => {
  return !models.B.some((model) => model.model === car.vehicle.model ) 
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In case, you want models which don't have cars.

```js
const cars = {"A":[{"id": "1","vehicle": {"model": "toyota"}},{"id":"2","vehicle": {"model": "vios"}},{"id":"3","vehicle": {"model": "honda"}},{"id":"4","vehicle": {"model": "eon"}},{"id":"5","vehicle": {"model": "motor"}}]};

const models = {"B":[{"model": "volkswagen"},{"model": "hyundai"},{"model": "honda"},{"model": "mitsubishi"},{"model": "bmw"}]};

var result = models.B.filter((model) => {
  return !cars.A.some((car) => model.model === car.vehicle.model ) 
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here is a lodash solution :

```js
const cars = {"A":[{"id": "1","vehicle": {"model": "toyota"}},{"id":"2","vehicle": {"model": "vios"}},{"id":"3","vehicle": {"model": "honda"}},{"id":"4","vehicle": {"model": "eon"}},{"id":"5","vehicle": {"model": "motor"}}]};

const models = {"B":[{"model": "volkswagen"},{"model": "hyundai"},{"model": "honda"},{"model": "mitsubishi"},{"model": "bmw"}]};

var result = _.filter(models.B, (model) =>
    !_.some(cars.A, (car) => model.model === car.vehicle.model));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js'></script>
```

Comment: What if I want to filter only in the models ? 
https://thumbs.gfycat.com/FakeFairCirriped-size_restricted.gif

array 1 shows the "Cars"
array 2 shows the "Models" - yes that's is a dialog box, that contains free vehicles

Comment: Do you mean get all those model which doesn't have cars? Yes this could be done. Updated the solution

Comment: do you have any idea how to do it in Reactjs ?

Comment: In ReactJs, you can use native javascript code, it will work. I have updated the solution to using loadash function.

Comment: B is the property inside the 2nd object, which is pointing to array of model object.

Comment: thanks man!  I Just add 
var result = _.filter(models.B, (model) =>
    !_.some(cars.A, (car) => `${model.model}` === `${car.vehicle.model}`));

It gets me an error undefined in React JS :)

But helps a lot ! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `_.isEqual` but u must make sure that the outer array is already sort

```
var array1 = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c']];
var array2 = [['b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']];
_.isEqual(array1.sort(), array2.sort()); //true
```

also with ES6 you can go like this :

```
array2.filter(e => !array1.includes(e));
```

Comment: sorry for the noob question...I'm confuse, what do you mean I need already sort ?

Comment: I mean you must sort the array before using _.isEqual then only it can compare and return the correct result.

Comment: {_.isEqual(_.sortBy(_.map(array1)), _.sortBy(_.map(array2, trips => _.get(this.state.trips, `[${trips}]`))), (v, idx) => {

<TableRowColumn>{`${v.model} - ${v.plate_no}`}</TableRowColumn>
})}

I try your advice to sort and then use isEqual but there's nothing to display.

Comment: this is the sample output https://thumbs.gfycat.com/FakeFairCirriped-size_restricted.gif

Answer (score 0):

Not in lodash but in plain javascript. The following code takes `var A` as what you've provided in `A` and likewise for `B`

```
const filterList = B.map(b => b.model);
const notInB = A.filter(a => filterList.indexOf(a.vehicle.model) < 0);
```

Values in `notInB` should contain values from `A` that's not in `B`, as the name implies.

**EDIT**

I've provided a jsfiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/zvc53j5g/

Comment: i try to convert you code into a Lodash function but there's still a problem :/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/gbxrho

screenshot of the code,, FYi, Im using the reacts Js and it is in order to render

Comment: I've provided a jsfiddle, seems to work fine, perhaps you can provide what is the `console.log` in your code printed

Answer (score -1):

why not just do a plain for loop and use `_.find` if model exists?

Comment: can you guide me how to do it ?